Duplicate Stable IDs - cannot publish?
Trying to publish docs in Stoplight, and it's giving me the error:

Your files have duplicate stable IDs. You must re-assign stable IDs before publishing.

I've never seen this error before, and I'm not even sure what "Stable IDs" are? The "re-assign" in the error message is a link, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

What is "Stoplight"?  Why is this question appropriate for a programming Q & A site?

https://stoplight.io/
It's a documentation platform for documenting apis and other coding situations.

Well, conceptually, in data stores, often a unique key is assigned to each element.  In this way, each thing can be pulled by passing that single value to find it.  That being said, somewhere this software is doing something like that, and you have non-unique values for these, most likely Integer values or sequentual numbers, and if for example, one entry is for ID 1 and the next is ID 1 as well, that program wouldn't know how to find the correct bit of data if that ID was not unique.  Hope that helps somehow, as no one on her uses stoplight or that tag would of already existed.

The solution is either delete and reimport in case there was a glitch on the import.  And if that doesn't work, you would have to look at the files and see if there is indeed a duplicate ID and resolve that.

This seems to have cleared up, so I believe Stoplight.io fixed an issue.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
